# Cannot connect with other mobile device using flutter_bluetooth_serial. Getting exception Cannot connect, exception occured. Can anyone help in this

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, flutter-dependencies

Cannot connect with other mobile device using `flutter_bluetooth_serial`. Getting exception `Cannot connect, exception occured`.
Here is the log :

```
selected 2C:4D:DE:7E:75:0A
D/FlutterBluePlugin(15068): Connecting to 2C:4D:DE:7E:75:0A (id: 12)
D/BluetoothAdapter(15068): cancelDiscovery(): called by: com.example.blue_classic
W/BluetoothAdapter(15068): getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback
I/flutter (15068): Cannot connect, exception occured
I/flutter (15068): PlatformException(connect_error, read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1, java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
I/flutter (15068):  at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readAll(BluetoothSocket.java:685)
I/flutter (15068):  at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readInt(BluetoothSocket.java:697)
I/flutter (15068):  at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:374)
I/flutter (15068):  at io.github.edufolly.flutterbluetoothserial.BluetoothConnection.connect(BluetoothConnection.java:57)
I/flutter (15068):  at io.github.edufolly.flutterbluetoothserial.BluetoothConnection.connect(BluetoothConnection.java:64)
I/flutter (15068):  at io.github.edufolly.flutterbluetoothserial.FlutterBluetoothSerialPlugin$FlutterBluetoothSerialMethodCallHandler.lambda$onMethodCall$4$io-github-edufolly-flutterbluetoothserial-FlutterBluetoothSerialPlugin$FlutterBluetoothSerialMethodCallHandler(FlutterBluetoothSerialPlugin.java:1007)
I/flutter (15068):  at io.github.edufolly.flutterbluetoothserial.FlutterBluetoothSerialPlugin$FlutterBluetoothSerialMethodCallHandler$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.r
```

Answer (score 0):

Till I know flutter_bluetooth_serial is only supporting classical Bluetooth (Ex. Handsfree, Headphones) not mobile device to mobile device

Comment: it is working with handfrees but I need connection between two mobile devices. Which package or technique I should use then?